# possibility of accessing an array reverse and forward in a single for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

i have been asked this question in an interview question that is that possible that you can access and array forward and reverse in a single for loop like for example he asked me you have an array of your name

```
  $array = ('s','a','f','i','r');
```

how would you do that ?

as people are asking about the output , the output should be

> **array forward = safir**
>
> **array backward = rifas**

Comment: I don't understand the question. What would be the desired outcome or the desired order the letters are accessed in the loop?

Comment: add expected output also..

Comment: Certainly you can do with an array inside a loop whatever you want, why not? The question probably is meant to make you think too complex. Automatically one thinks of an array the loop iterates over. But the question actually does not mention this. But even _if_ that is what is meant, then sure, you can use a for loop and increment or decrement the index variable (pointer) to your liking inside the loop.

Comment: Can you please post your expected output

Comment: simple iterating an array forward and backward ?  he told me any array , so i just mention my name

Comment: Two words: `array` and `reverse`... Google it, then how would ***you*** do it?

Comment: @Slyvain be shameless to ask for help on stack overflow haahah

Comment: @CyedSafir, sure you can try, and there is already an answer, but I strongly believe that the best way to learn anything in coding is to at least try to write some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compute the respective access index in the loop:

```php
$forward = $backwards = '';
for ($pos = 0, $lastIndex = count($array) - 1; $pos <= $lastIndex; $pos++) {
    $forward .= $array[$pos];
    $backwards .= $array[$lastIndex - $pos];
}
```

Comment: Just updated the code to reflect the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
$j = count($array)-1;
$forward="";
$reverse="";
for($i=0;$i<=count($array)-1;$i++){
    $forward.= $array[$i];
    $reverse.= $array[$j];
    $j--;
}
```